# Squid3 Refusing Connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, proxy, squid

I'm attempting to use Squid as a simple web proxy, however, after upgrading my server to Ubuntu 17.04 this has stopped working.

I've disabled ufw, so the firewall isn't an issue. I can `telnet` other ports and connect over `ssh` so I can clearly communicate with the server. Further to this a `telnet localhost 3128` works absolutely fine but with an external one it gets dropped.

My `squid.conf`:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
cache_peer {redacted company filtering server} parent 80 0 no-query default
never_direct allow all
http_access allow all
#http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 127.0.0.1:3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

The results of `netstat -plnt`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2222/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1108/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1307/smbd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2061/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1627/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1307/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1699/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2222/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1108/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2204/gitea
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1307/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1627/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1307/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1699/nginx: master
```

Results of `telnet localhost 3128`:

```
seeng@GITServ:~$ telnet localhost 3128
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Results of `telnet {hostIP} 3128` from remote machine:

```
PS C:\Users\James.Hughes> telnet {hostIP} 3128
Connecting To 10.230.48.93...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3128: Connect failed
```

This server is only accessible from within the company network, however, via the `cache peer` it has access to the internet. So essentially I want any computer that can connect to this server to be proxied to the cache peer (which then sends it to the WWW) which worked before the upgrade, there is no worry with regards to security or access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I can see in your post. First, squid seems to be not running or listening on port 3128 as it is clear from the output of `netstat`. There is no listening process on port 3128.

Another issue is that your squid configuration defines http_port as:

```
http_port 127.0.0.1:3128
```

This means it will listen only on loopback interface and so no connection from any host other than localhost.

Comment: Weird, it was running on 3128 before, I must have had the service stopped when I took the netstat for the post and forgot to check it. As for your comment about the loopback interface, that seems to be the same conclusion that I arrived at, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the use of `127.0.0.1:3128` as part of the `http_port` directive.

If I change that to just `3128` it works just fine. I guess it was only listening for connections from localhost on that port.